# Problem with screen of image when webdriver is in headless option

Tags: python, image, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I have problem with screenshot of image, when the webdriver is on headless mode.
Without option.headless = True

```
time.sleep(2)
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="img"]')
time.sleep(3)
img.screenshot('C:/foo.png')
time.sleep(3)
```

[image]

When i used it:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.headless = True

time.sleep(2)
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="img"]')
time.sleep(3)
img.screenshot('C:/foo.png')
time.sleep(3)
```

[image]

I also try that options:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.headless = True
option.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

[image]

For all pictures sizes are okay (172,62). The second picture looks pretty good, but is covered by a strip at the bottom that reminds me of moving the page to the side(?) (that is not end of site, on the bottom also have some buttons and ads). I tried to set the browser to normal size without the GUI, but then it crops the image (img 3). Some solution?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan but js won't work in headless.

Comment: @Owneds add the website !!

Comment: @Adgogo I add that code and it works. Now i can see full image. :) Where was the problem, because u write js not work in headless?

`element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="img"]')
 coordinates = element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
 driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo({}, {});'.format(coordinates['x'], coordinates['y']))
 element.screenshot('C:/foo.png')`

Comment: it did work in headless mode for you?

Comment: yes, it works now